# Wrap jar as .app (OSX) and (.exe) for deployment?

Tags: java, windows, macos, deployment

I have a jar file for an application i've made and would like to deploy it now as an .app and .exe file.

**Is this possible?**

I've seen applications do this before and i don't know how it's done. 
Is there a tool/eclipse plugin I need? 
Would i need a developer subscription with apple for OSX? 
I don't know where to go next, some recommended steps to take would be amazing thank you!

So far for testing, i've been doing **Run > Run As > Java Application** from within eclipse.
As stated in the title I wanted the .app and .exe to act as a wrapper for the .jar.

Comment: @lunchosrock, uh no. read the question. "wrapper" not convert to .exe, i want the exe to run the jar file.

Comment: Oh, I read it, that's why I flagged it. If this is not what you're looking for, then reformulate your question. Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: That suggested duplicate is not what i'm looking for and the answers given on it do not solve my question regarding .app for OSX. I don't see why it should remain flagged as so.

Comment: @ThatGuy343: The way your question is worded, it would appear to be a duplicate. I'd recommend you edit the additional information from your comment into your question. There's no actual close vote, so the "flag" is merely a comment.

Comment: It is still unclear what you're actually trying to ask.  If you "want the exe to run the jar file" rather than create an installer / stand-alone executable, what does the question have to do with deployment?  Why don't you just use a batch script / shell script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For OSX consider making [OSX Application Bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/03-JavaDeployment/JavaDeployment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001885-SW1)

For Windows consider [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: just what i was looking for!

Comment: @ThatGuy343 Since you mentioned Eclipse, I'll add that there's a "Mac OS X Application Bundle" option under Export.  It should be able to export a Run Configuration as an app.

Comment: @whiskeyspider Useful tip! Thank you, had no idea that was there.